# Extjs4 for ipad web application: How do I prevent the keyboard from popping up on datepicker

Tags: extjs4

Extjs4 for ipad web application: How do I prevent the keyboard from popping up on datepicker?

```
{
 xtype: 'datefield',
 name: 'myDate',
 fieldLabel: 'Date'             
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set it as non-editable: `editable: false`